# Let $z$ be complex number such that $|{5z+\frac{1}{z}}|=3$ and $\arg(z)= \theta$, then maximum value of $\cos(2\theta)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> > Let $z$ be complex number such that $|{5z+\frac{1}{z}}|=3$ and $\arg(z)= \theta$, then maximum value of $\cos(2\theta)$

**My Approach:**

I took $z=x+iy$
So $|{5(x+iy)+\frac{1}{x+iy}}|=3$

$\implies$ $\big|5(x+iy)+\frac{(x-iy)}{x^2+y^2}\big|=3$

$\implies$ $|\big(5x+\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\big)+i\big(5y-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}\big)|=3$

$\implies$ $(5x+\frac{x}{x^2+y^2})^2+(5y-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2})^2=9$

$\implies$ $25(x^2+y^2)+10(\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2})+\frac{x^2+y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}=9$

$\implies$ $25(x^2+y^2)^2+x^2-19y^2+1=0$

**How to Approach Further in this method only to calculate $\theta$?**

**I know how to solve this question by putting $z=r(cos\theta + i sin\theta)$**

**My doubt is can I get answer of this question by putting $z=x+iy$** ?

Comment: Hint: write down $\cos 2\theta$ in cartesian form, then look more closely at the expressions in the last-but-one step.